# javascript to raise popup window on third page accessed

Tags: javascript, popup

After a person has toured my website for N pages, I would like to raise a popup window asking them if they would like to subscribe to my newsletter.

I've found sample code to raise a popup after a delay of some seconds, I've found samples for asking only once, but not one that can track the number of pages traversed.

Where can I find sample JS code to raise a window after a certain number of pages have been traversed?

My simple minded analysis is that normally each invocation of the script on N pages would be a different invocation, and hence would not have any record of the previous page's invocation.  So each copy would have to read a cookie set by the previous copy, increment it, and store back.  Then, when N=3 and whatever other conditions I think are appropriate are satisified, the popup is triggered.

Comment: Just a heads up it may not make a lot of sense to annoy your potential customers like that.

Comment: DA:  I agree.  Which is why I want to do it only once, do it only after they have been on for N pages -- they are obviously interested in my site, and have spend over M minutes on my site. A site I use has a John Deere ad popup every time I open a new window.  THAT's annoying.

Comment: This question has far better answers: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040883/running-a-javascript-after-x-number-of-page-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct! You'll need cookies of some sort, whether tracked server side or just good old fashioned javascript cookies.

Here's the best rundown I've seen of how to implement them: [Quirksmode Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

To update the value of the cookie to track page count - again assuming you aren't doing this server-side - you'll need to reset the cookie and set a new one with the new value. Updating/changing a value of an existing cookie just isn't really a supported operation of cookies.

Or you could just create 3 cookies, I guess. Whatever floats your integer ;)

Comment: Nice answer.  Coupled to the other answer, and similar scripts, I think I can roll a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

On clicking Links do a push to the HTML5 history API and check length of history. You may also add an eventhandler to all links on your page.

```
//first 2 paraemeters could be NULL, last is the URL
history.pushState(data, event.target.textContent, event.target.href);

//check length of history
history.length
```

more abouth HML5 history API: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

Edit: actually you should not need the push event for ordinary Links, just test it with `console.log(history.length);`