# Running a javascript after x number of page views

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show a marketing popup after users has been on my site for either a certain amount of time or after a certain number of page views. Eg. i want it to pop after the user has browsed 3 pages.

How do i do this using either JavaScript/jQuery or PHP?

Comment: what have you tried, have you used google to look for the asnwer as I found 3 results by looking for 'display message after 3 page views'

Comment: Yeah, guess i googled for the wrong stuff. Tried with "jquery check how many page views" and such phrases without any success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, people proposed PHP solution, I will complement javascript one. Here is very simple `localStorage` approach:

```
if ((localStorage.pageViews = (+localStorage.pageViews || 0) + 1) > 3) {
    alert('Marketing');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vBLv5/ (refresh page 3 times).

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you just would embed the javascript if x number of visits have taken place (save it into a cookie / session)

In Javascript, you'd save the same information + time on page in the cookie or localstorage and trigger the popup...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the $_SESSION from PHP and store an integer in it.
Then check that integer versus your requirement for the amount of visits.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_runs']))
{
    $_SESSION['page_runs'] = 1;
}else{
    $_SESSION['page_runs'] = $_SESSION['page_runs'] + 1;

    if($_SESSION['page_runs'] == 3)
    {
        echo '<script></script>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if( isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) )
   {
      $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
   }
   else
   {
      $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
   }
   $msg = "You have visited this page ".  $_SESSION['counter'];
   $msg .= "in this session.";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Setting up a PHP session</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  echo ( $msg ); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Cookie when the user visits your site for the first time with value = 1

```
$_COOKIE['visit_count'] = 1;
```

On subsequent page visits, you can increase this value,

```
$_COOKIE['visit_count'] = $_COOKIE['visit_count'] + 1;
```

And compare this value to do the necessary action.

```
if($_COOKIE['visit_count'] === N) {
    //Do some stuff
}
```

You can access the cookie in Javascript. But make sure Cookie is not httponly.